# Graphql API Call /w Query using PHP

Tags: php, api, curl, graphql

Struggling to figure out how to make graphql api calls with PHP. I'm trying to use the tezos domain API to convert a .tez domain to an address. My query is working well in their "playground", just can't get this translated to php.

Attempt 1:

```
$apiUrl = 'https://api.tezos.domains/graphql';
$query = '{
           domains(where: { name: { in: "' . $wallet . '" } }) {
            items {
              address
            }
          }
        }';
$data = @file_get_contents($apiUrl, false, stream_context_create([
 'http' => [
  'method' => 'POST',
  'content' => json_encode(['query' => $query]),
 ]
]));
$results = json_decode($data, true);
echo $results;
$wallet = $results['data'];
```

Attempt 2:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.tezos.domains/graphql" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"query":"{domains(where: {name: { in:"elli0t.tez"}}) {items {address}}}"}'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
    array(
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br',
        'Content-Type: application/json', 
        'Accept: application/json',
        'Connection: keep-alive',
        'DNT: 1',
        'Origin: https://api.tezos.domains' )
    ); 

$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($result);

$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

print_r($info);
```

Attempt 2 at least returns me something.. it says I'm missing a query. Any thoughts?

Here is the curl command generated from the api's playground that appears to work. I'm just having trouble converting this to PHP:

```
curl 'https://api.tezos.domains/graphql' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Origin: https://api.tezos.domains' --data-binary '{"query":"{\n   domains(where: { name: { in: \"elli0t.tez\" } }) {\n    items {\n      address\n    }\n  }\n}"}' --compressed
```

Comment: were you able to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

From the GraphQL Docs I found this: a basic query with arguments:

```
    {
  human(id: "1000") {
    name
    height
  }
}
```

Whereas your domains query looks like this:

```
{
       domains(where: { name: { in: "' . $wallet . '" } }) {
        items {
          address
        }
      }
    }
```

What strikes me as wrong syntax, because you can't find anywhere in the GraphQL Documentation an example for a structure like:

```
{
    domains(where: { ... })
}
```

I don't know GraphQL, but I would pinpoint it on the colons inside the argument. The only thing I could find where this is allowed is using variables for creating mutations:

```
   mutation CreateReviewForEpisode($ep: Episode!, $review: ReviewInput!)
{
  createReview(episode: $ep, review: $review) {
    stars
    commentary
  }
}
```

So I guess what might be happening that the domain query breakes, or you are chaining your queries together.

I hope this might help you.

Comment: Hmm okay thanks for the response. I'm using a graphql explorer in the api's "playground" to generate the query string, which returns the proper response, so I think my query is correct. It also generates the curl command that it uses in the playground, which I've added to my original post. I saw some missing headers that I added (which I updated my code with as well in the original post), but now I'm just getting no response.